# If the anode attracts negative ions and the cathode postive ions. Then why do electrons flow from anode to cathode?

Tags: batteries, charge

I know that in a battery:
The anode is where oxidation takes place (the anode losses electrons).
The cathode is where reduction takes place (the cathode gains electrons).

But I am confused why is the anode called anode if it is providing electrons instead of attracting them?
Why do we say Cathode is negative and Anode is positive if the former takes electrons and the latter provides them?

Comment: A North wind blows from the North, a Southerly flow goes towards the South. Why do people name things strangely? If you don't like the names, then name things by describing what they do. If you you are in a situation where you are being tested on the names, then learn the names. If you suspect ambiguity in a communication, then clarify with descriptions.

Comment: See the question and accepted answer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10232/cathode-anode-rechargeable-battery

Comment: FWIW, for vacuum tubes, the cathode is negative and emits electrons and the anode is positive and absorbs electrons.

Comment: Easy. The person that decided to name 'em that felt differently to you. For that person, *you've* got it all backwards.

Comment: The basic problem seems to be that you haven't defined if you are charging or discharging this battery.

Comment: The chemists developed a clear standard naming well before the electron was discovered. See [here](https://web.mst.edu/~gbert/BATTERY/battery.html) for a thorough discussion from a chemistry perspective or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anode) for the Wiki discussion. Or for battery naming conventions see [here](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/bu_104b_building_blocks_of_a_battery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not usual to talk about anode and cathode of a battery (or cell) in electroncs, it's more a chemistry thing.

In chemistry the anode is the terminal that is producing external electron current and the cathode is consuming an equal current.

> I know that in a battery: The anode is where oxidation takes place (the anode losses electrons). The cathode is where reduction takes place (the cathode gains electrons).

> But I am confused why is the anode called anode if it is providing electrons instead of attracting them?

It's called an anode because that's the terminology chemists chose.
the anode oxidises releasing electrons which flow into the external circuit
electrons have negative charge so the electrons flowing out of the anode mean conventional current flowing into it.

The voltage on the anode is immaterial, so I can't say if it's attracting or repelling electrons. it depends on the direction of the current (ie. if the cell is being charged or discharged) which terminal will be anode and which cathode not it electrical potential.

> Why do we say Cathode is negative and Anode is positive

We don't. consider for instance the zener diode. and most rectifiers most of the time.

> if the former takes electrons and the latter provides them?

Chemists worry about the direction of current flow to determine cathodeness,
but in electronics anode and cathode are fixed properties of the device.

Answer (score 0):

They (electrons) flow from cathode to anode. What’s got you confused is that electron flow is the opposite of *conventional current* flow, which pre-dates electron theory by about 100 years or so. (Ben Franklin vs. JJ Thomson.)

The math still works out either way as long as you’re consistent.

Inside the battery itself, electrons are separated from ions at the cathode and recombined with other ions at the anode during discharge. Charging reverses this process.